# Why does my formula in a table crash Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, formulas

I have a table defined in Excel.  It has about 20 columns and 20,000 rows.

In one column, I'd like to put the following formula

=IF([@[Customer End]]=[@[Effective End]],1,0)

Basically, for that contract, if the contract start date equals the overall customer date, put a 1.  This is to call out which contracts signify the beginning & end of the relationships.

But as soon as I put in this formula, my Excel hangs.  It's particularly odd because I was able to successfully do it for the start dates.  Excel worked a bit but was able to process it.  But Excel just gives up when I do it for the end dates.

If you can offer any guidance, I would much appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: does the initial table come from a query? I have found if you add in calculated columns from a query, it will spend an extraordinary amount of time processing the data. By moving a calculated column into the query, I cut the refresh time for my query from 15+ minutes to ~15 seconds

Comment: Hi Sean thanks for your reply.  What kind of query are you referring to?  The Excel table in my case is just raw data that I downloaded from a server into a CSV, then renamed to Excel file.  Then I defined the table based off that raw table.  I have no external data links.

Comment: That should work fine. I wonder if it's triggering other calculations

Comment: That is so bizarre.  So anytime I tried to delete the column or move the column, Excel froze.  There were no dependent formulas.  I inserted a new column, put the formula above in, and it worked in 2 seconds.  So now I have this legacy column in my table that Excel throws a fit if I try to remove...oh well :)